# re-export Typescript enum from namespace?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have an enum definition in module 'some-lib'. I want to re-export it from a namespace in my module, something like this:

```
import { PaymentType } from 'some-lib';

namespace Payout {
    export enum PaymentType = PaymentType;
}
```

I'm not having any luck. I want to do this in order to alias the enum and put it into a different namespace to avoid collisions with other types with the same name. I don't want to have to define a duplicate copy of the enum in my code, and have to maintain all the enum values.

Is there any way Typescript supports this currently?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, there's a way to do this, e.g.:

```
import { PaymentType as _PaymentType } from 'some-lib';


namespace Payout {
  export import PaymentType = _PaymentType;
}
```

or alternatively:

```
import * as SomeLibTypes from 'some-lib';


namespace Payout {
  export import PaymentType = SomeLibTypes.PaymentType;
}
```

reference: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20273#issuecomment-347079963

Comment: Outstanding! So simple, but I never would have figured out the proper syntax. Thanks!

Comment: I get the following error:

 import =` is not supported by @babel/plugin-transform-typescript
    Please consider using `import <moduleName> from '<moduleName>';` alongside Typescript's --allowSyntheticDefaultImports option.