# exporting enum from typescript type definition file

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm writing the type definitions for a library I'm using. One function in the library identifies the mouse button clicked by an integer:

```js
 //index.d.ts
 export as namespace myLib;
 // activates the library listening for a specific mouse button
 function activate(button : number ) : void
```

I introduced an enum to make this nicer:

```js
//index.d.ts
export as namespace myLib;
export enum MouseButton {
    LEFT = 1,
    MIDDLE = 2,
    RIGHT = 4
}

export function activate(button : MouseButton ) : void;
```

Now, when I import this function and use it, everything compiles but I guess the enum is stripped and undefined when executed in the browser. The error message says `Cannot read property 'LEFT' of undefined`.

Therefore I rearranged the files like so:

```js
//MouseButton.ts
export enum MouseButton {
    LEFT = 1,
    MIDDLE = 2,
    RIGHT = 4
}

//index.d.ts
export as namespace myLib;
import {MouseButton} from MouseButton;
export {MouseButton} from MouseButton;
export function activate(button : MouseButton ) : void;
```

Now I can `import {MouseButton} from "myLib/MouseButton"; import * as myLib from "myLib"`. But this requires two imports. Referencing `myLib.MouseButton` still compiles but doesn't run.

Is there any way to import and reference the `MouseButton` enum via the `myLib` imported via the `import * as myLib` statement? I'm not only looking for an answer explaining how to do it but for one explaining why my solution doesn't work or why it isn't possible. Hints to resources explaining what's wrong are also appreciated

PS: I also tried the syntax suggested here [re-export Typescript enum from namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47701270/re-export-typescript-enum-from-namespace) but that didn't work either.

PPS: The module in question is a UMD module from the cornerstone project (https://github.com/cornerstonejs/cornerstone) used in an angular 6 project.

Comment: What is the source code where the error `Cannot read property 'LEFT' of undefined` occurred?

Comment: This code is part of an angular project (sorry for not mentioning that). The error message is thrown in the console of the executing browser.

Comment: Do you use the enum `MouseButton` as a reverse map : `MouseButton[button]` ? If not, I don't know why this pure TypeScript thing is leaking to JavaScript, unless a JaveScript bundle issue with the modules.

Comment: Perhaps, it's an issue related to the type definition syntax. It depends on the type of JavaScript library: what kind of module: UMD? pure ES6? ... Try to find a similar library to get inspired by its definition file. Without this library and its usage (i.e. more code), it's difficult to reason about this issue.

Comment: Nope. My usage of MouseButton is as follows: `myLib.activate(MouseButton.LEFT);` (with the two-imports version). but I would like it to be myLib.activate(myLib.MouseButton.LEFT)`. What do you mean by "leaking"? should it be compiled away and replaced by the enum's value?

Comment: The library is a UMD library. It's cornerstone (https://github.com/cornerstonejs/cornerstone) and the api I'm trying to call is cornerstoneTools.wwwc.activate .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171922/discussion-between-t-animal-and-romain-deneau).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

*(To complete t.animal's own answer)*

Declaration files are difficult to make: see the long [documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html). Sometimes looking in existing .d.ts files can help.

Regarding `enum`, declaring them as `const enum` is a clean and simple approach. It's
what is done for jquery for instance, see [@types/jquery/index.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jquery/index.d.ts) for `Mouse` and `Key`. It's handy because standard enums are compiled in JavaScript as arrays while `const enum` members are compiled directly as values ; see [TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=enum%20A%20%7B%20a%2C%20b%2C%20c%20%7D%0D%0Aconst%20i%20%3D%20A.a%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20enum%20B%20%7B%20a%2C%20b%2C%20c%20%7D%0D%0Aconst%20j%20%3D%20B.a%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A).

Comment: How to reexport it?

Comment: @Jose: I don't understand your question. Perhaps it deserves its own full stack overflow question.

Answer (score 32):

Solved it by the help of [Romain Denau's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50564756/exporting-enum-from-typescript-type-definition-file#comment88145281_50564756) above. It nudged me in the right direction: What code does the typescript compiler generate from an enum (see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#enums-at-runtime)? Declaring the enum `const` allows the typescript compiler to completely swap the identifier with the respective value, effectively inlining it. No more leakage of the enum into the production code. Thanks!

```
//index.d.ts
export as namespace myLib;

export const enum MouseButton {
    LEFT = 1,
    MIDDLE = 2,
    RIGHT = 4
}

export function activate(button : MouseButton ) : void;
```

Comment: "What code does the typescript compiler generate from an enum definition?" - this.

Comment: On the same page it also mentioned pitfalls of using `const` - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#const-enum-pitfalls. Is that an issue for you? Also this article explained more on this topic: https://ncjamieson.com/dont-export-const-enums/. I am confused.

Answer (score 9):

From my short research on the topic, I noticed that exporting the enums from the type definition file using `export enum const` is a bad idea. Since you have to enable the `--isolatedModules` flag which isn't even possible in say `create-react-app` and it can get messy.

Instead, I myself used the normal syntax in my `shared.d.ts` file:

```
  export enum EReviewStatus {
    PENDING = 'PENDING',
    SENT = 'SENT'
  }
```

And then I have a `.js` file, which is imported in the `package.json` main-block eg:

```
"main": "shared.js",
```

Where I have (using CommonJS export to make it compatible in both Node.js and frontend):

```
module.exports.EReviewStatus = {
  PENDING: 'PENDING',
  SENT: 'SENT'
}
```

Which works and I think is better practise, as now your code is clearly separated from the types.

Comment: I didn't get the shared.js file part. Could you be more precise on what you've done please ? I'm in a situation where I cannot disable `--isolatedModules` and your solution would save my life

Comment: @Devz so I have two files: shared.d.ts and shared.js (the names are arbitrary). They are imported from the package.json using "types": "shared.d.ts" and "main": "shared.js". I don't know how else I can explain it. I updated my solution to use CommonJS since I wasnt able to import the js from my Node.js backend without it (and I dont want to compile it).

Comment: Yeah attempting to use path, composite, and references does not work as well as this option.

Comment: This is not DRY. To make it DRY, you could have a `shared.ts` and generate the `.js` and `.d.ts` from that. Or just write the whole project as TS.

Answer (score 2):

You can't export enum from `.d.ts` file. Just create another file maybe `constants.ts` and export the same enum from that file.
Because enum is treated more like a variable rather than a type or interface.

Hope it helps!.

Comment: Found this the hard way. 
This should be the recommended answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a similar approach to @TeemuK:

```js
// Define a constant you can export
export const ReviewStatusEnum {
    PENDING = 'PENDING',
    SENT = 'SENT'
} as const

// And infer the valid values from it for typing
export type ReviewStatusType = keyof typeof ReviewStatusEnum
```

This leaves you without the need of duplicating your enum values.