# Why do I need `const` in front enum in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have below typescript code in `type.d.ts`:

```
export const enum SearchType {
  RENT = 0,
  SELL = 1,
}
```

In other files, I use `import { SearchType } from './type'` to import this enum.
It doesn't compile if I remove `const` from the `export` line.
I don't understand why I need a `const` in this case.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50564756